# Replacing expressions with `sed`

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I have a SQL file that contains many `INSERT` statements, but they are all combined on one line. I was trying to use `sed` to separate them on different lines, but I couldn't get it to work. Here is the command I am using:

```
sed 's/);INSERT/);\nINSERT/' myfile.sql
```

But this command is not working. What's wrong with it? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a "g" to the end of the regex to tell it to work on all matches rather than just the first found.

```
sed 's/);INSERT/);\nINSERT/g' myfile.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

where did the file come from?

if it's from a Mac, there's probably a carriage-return ("\r" or ASCII 0x13) after the semi-colon.  Macs use CR as a line separator, while *nix uses line-feed characters aka "newline" ("\n" or ASCII 0x0a).

MS-Dos/Windows uses the two character sequence CR/LF ("\r\n") to separate lines.

also, if the input is all one line, then the s/search/replace/ will only replace the *first* match on the line.  you need the g modifier to make it a "global" search-and-replace.

my guess is that the file is from a Mac because you say it's all just one line...a windows file would still be treated as multiple lines (because there is a \n for unix to see).

try something like:

```
sed 's/);[\n\r]*INSERT/);\nINSERT/g' myfile.sql
```

that will match your string with zero or more of \n and/or \r characters immediately after the semi-colon.  also note the /g modifier.

if that fails, i'd be inclined to try perl rather than sed (but i prefer perl REs anyway).  you can slurp the entire file into a scalar string and use the /s and /g modifiers to pretty much ignore line-endings.  you can also use the \R character class which matches just about any line-ending known - according to the perlre man page, it matches:

(?>\x0D\x0A?|[\x0A-\x0C\x85\x{2028}\x{2029}])

Comment: As OP stated, all the INSERT statements are on one line.

Comment: yes, i did read that.  and even mentioned it in my reply.  however what appears at a casual glance to be just one line on one operating system may not actually BE just one line if the file came from another OS with different conventions about what constitutes a line-break.  in any case including [\n\r]* in the search pattern won't make any difference if they aren't actually there - the * matches zero-or-more, not one-or-more.

Comment: doh.  just re-read my post.  \r is ascii 0x0D (decimal 13, not hex 13)

Comment: Thanks for the information, but the file did not come from a Mac. I've used my expression after appending the `g`, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of the \n, insert a control-M character.  You can do this in most modern shells by typing control-V control-M.
- Also, don't forget /g to make the change global to everything in the line.

.

```
 sed 's/);INSERT/);^MINSERT/g' myfile.sql
                   |
                  control-V control-M
```

Comment: Why would you prefer Windows newlines?